# How to let your App display a dialog (AndroidStudio)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialog

My activity should show a dialog when launched.

This is my java class "PrivacyDialog":

```
public class PrivacyDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Information")
                .setMessage("test")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

       return builder.create();

    }
}
```

This is the function which opens the dialog in my activity.

```
 public void openDialog () {


        PrivacyDialog privacyDialog = new PrivacyDialog();
        privacyDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"PrivacyDialog");

    }
```

**My Problem:**

The App crashes every time it executes the openDialog function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You creating alert dialog inside the custom dialog, that is wrong. You should provide custom layout inside inflater.

```
class MyCustomDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        // Do all the stuff to initialize your custom view
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false)
    }
}
```

Dismiss

```
dialogFragment.dismiss();
```

PS:
Since DialogFragment is an actual fragment you will only need to create a fragment transaction and call the show method of

```
    val dialog: MyCustomDialogFragment = MyCustomDialogFragment()
    val fm: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    dialog.show(fm, "fragment_dialog")
```

Xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I changed my code how you suggested however I still have problems with the .show() function. AndroidStudio underlines the content (ft, "dialog") red.

Comment: Ok, try now. I tested it in my project and it works

Comment: import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.
Define ui actions in ovrride onViewCreated

Comment: Thank you it works! My problem was that I didn't define ui actions in override onViewCreate